# How to restrict fields returned by stackexchange api, and turn off paging?

Tags: json, python-2.7, stackexchange-api

I'd like to have a list of just the current titles for all questions in one of the smaller (less than 10,000 questions) stackexchange site. I tried the interactive utility here: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions and it both reports the result as a json at the bottom, and produces the requesting url at the top.  For example:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=apples&site=cooking
```

returns this JSON in my browser:

```
{"items":[{"tags":["apples","crumble"],"owner":{ ...
...
...],"has_more":true,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":252}
```

*What is* quota? It was 10,000 on one search on one site, but suddenly it's only 300 here.

I won't be doing this very often, what I'd like is the quickest way to edit that (or similar of course) url so I can get a list of all of the titles on a small site. I don't understand how to use paging, and I don't need any of the other fields. I don't care if I get them, but I'm thinking if I exclude them I can have more at once.

If I need to script it, python (2.7) is my preferred (only) language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`quota_max` is the number of requests your application is allowed per day. 300 is the default for an unregistered application. This used to be mentioned directly on the page describing [throttles](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), but seems to have been removed. [Here is](https://stackapps.com/a/3057/24319) historical information describing the default.

To increase this to 10,000, you need to [register an application](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) and then [authenticate](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) by passing an access token in your script.

---

To get all titles on a site, you can use a Python library to help:

- [StackAPI](https://stackapps.com/questions/6841/stackapi-another-python-wrapper). The answer below will use this library. **DISCLAIMER:** I wrote this library
- [Py-StackExchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python)
- [SEAPI](https://stackapps.com/questions/3881/seapi-a-lightweight-python-wrapper-for-the-stack-exchange-api)
- [StackPy](https://stackapps.com/questions/3417/stack-py-a-python-module-for-accessing-the-stack-exchange-2-1-api)

---

Assuming you have registered your application and authenticated we can proceed.

First, install StackAPI ([documentation](http://stackapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)):

```
pip install stackapi
```

This code will then grab the 10,000 most recent questions (`max_pages` * `page_size`) for the site `hardwarerecs`. Each page costs you one API hit, so the more items per page, the few API calls.

```
from stackapi import StackAPI

SITE = StackAPI('hardwarerecs')
SITE.page_size = 100
SITE.max_pages = 100

# Filter to only get question title and link
filter = '!BHMIbze0EQ*ved8LyoO6rNjkuLgHPR'

questions = SITE.fetch('questions', filter=filter)
```

In the `questions` variable is a dictionary that looks *very* similar to the API output, except that the library did all the paging for you. Your data is in `questions['data']` and, in this case, contains a list of dictionaries that look like this:

```
[
...
{u'link': u'http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/29/sound-board-to-replace-a-gl2200-in-a-house-of-worship-foh-setting',
 u'title': u'Sound board to replace a GL2200 in a house-of-worship FOH setting?'},
{ u'link': u'http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31/passive-gps-tracker-logger',
  u'title': u'Passive GPS tracker/logger'}
...
]
```

---

This result set is limited to only the title and the link because of the [`filter`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) we applied. You can find the appropriate filter by adjusting what fields you want in the web UI and copying the filter field.

The `hardwarerecs` parameter that is passed when creating the `SITE` parameter is the first part of the site's domain URL. Alternatively, you can find it by looking at the `api_site_parameter` for your site when looking at the [`/sites`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) end point.

Comment: OK thank you! - you've understood exactly what I needed to know, and given me an answer I can use! I've looked at those links and it doesn't jump out at me right away why `filter` is set to a cryptic-looking string or how I would have arrived at that, after I install I can read further using `help()` or `.__doc__`      ( `filter = '!BHMIbze0EQ*ved8LyoO6rNjkuLgHPR'` )

Comment: Can you explain how this cryptic-looking string works: `filter = '!BHMIbze0EQ*ved8LyoO6rNjkuLgHPR'`, and why it is so long and cryptic? Thanks!

Comment: Here is a [long technical discussion](https://kevinmontrose.com/2012/01/11/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-implementing-filters/). If you just want the appropriate filter for your API calls though, you can get this by navigating to the API endpoint you are using in the documentation ([/questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) for example) and adjusting the "filter" in the "Try It" section to include the fields you want. Click save, and you'll notice that "default" changes to a cryptic string like above. Copy that string to your application.

Comment: OK I'll take a closer look, thank you! So this cryptic, unreadable thing is not your idea - it's a stackexchange thing? Is it generated some kind of algorithm that compresses structured information into the tiniest space possible using the subset of ASCII that is legal in the middle of a url? I ask because I have [another question about decoding unreadable ASCII](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37640137/3904031) in urls that hasn't had much attention.

Comment: Correct. The filter string is generated by Stack Exchange.